# Build configuration shortcut in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have a build configuration shortcut in VSCode?

In "includePath" and "defines" of "c_cpp_properties.json", I have some variables that depend on build configuration.

For example, let's say that I have two build configurations, namely A and B:

```
// BUILD CONFIGURATION A
"includePath": [
    path_used_in_both_configurations,
    path_used_only_in_configuration_A
],
"defines": [
    define_used_in_both_configurations,
    defined_used_only_in_configuration_A
]

// BUILD CONFIGURATION B
"includePath": [
    path_used_in_both_configurations,
    path_used_only_in_configuration_B
],
"defines": [
    define_used_in_both_configurations,
    defined_used_only_in_configuration_B
]
```

When I need to switch between two configurations, I manually delete old configuration-specific paths and defines and add new ones. Is there an easier way to do this? I do not even know how to google this.

Comment: Is there no 'Debug' and 'Release' option on the build toolbar?

Comment: What if I have 5 build configurations.. Plus I do not know how to link build options to c_cpp_properties.json file.